# При использовании drush ошибка - "/usr/bin/env: «php\r»: no such file or directory"

Tags: php, drupal

Ubuntu 18.04, drupal 8.7, drush 9.7.1
По идее оно должно искать просто "php", но ищет "php/r". Видел такую же  проблему на англ stackoverflow, но до конца не понял.
Вот ссылка на тот вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794312/debian-usr-bin-env-php-r-no-such-file-or-directory/49794689

Comment: Пересохранить файл с правильными переносами строк

Comment: пробывал, в итоге вообще не смог пользоваться многими командами, система не видела env, пришлось переустанавливать coreutils